# x-www-form-urlencoded and UTF-8

Tags: forms, http, servlets, unicode, utf-8

Java web application servlet reads the form POST request parameters using wrong encoding. The web page renders the UTF-8 correctly and contains the following tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

The form in question doesn't specify any specific charset, which means it should use the UTF-8 as default. When I capture the POST request using browser tools, the URL-encoded value sent to the server actually represents the correct Unicode input. The request content-type header is set as follows.

```
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

However, when I try to read the request parameters in Servlet, the wrong encoding is used for the string.

```
String values[] = request.getParameterValues(key);
```

How do I enable the Servlet requests (all HTTP methods) to use UTF-8?

Comment: HTML meta tag is ignored when HTML document is retrieved via a HTTP response. You need to set the desired encoding in the HTTP response instead like as instructed in every highly upvoted answer about how to correctly use UTF-8 in a servlet based application. As to the multipart/form-data encoding problem, there have been bugs in existing servers. If you tell which one exactly you're using you might have more chance on an answer. Don't forget to try in the meanwhile the latest version of your specific server.

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type">` in HTML 4, and `<meta charset>` in HTML 5, overrides the charset specified in the HTTP headers. Just about every browser supports that nowadays. Also, `<form>` has an optional `accept-charset` attribute that specifies the charset(s) the submitter MUST use regardless of the HTML's charset.